# Error 302 when executing AT+CMGL="ALL"

Tags: c#, serial-port, at-command

I'm programming a modem using AT commands. When I execute `AT+CMGL="ALL"`, I get an inconsistent result. Most of the time, it returned Error 302 (operation not allowed). At other times, it returns the list of messages. I'm using Multitech MTCBA-G-U.FA. This inconsistency makes it difficult to know what is happening.

I get the same behaviour when using putty as well. In all instances where AT+CMGL fails, AT always works returning OK.

regards

Answer (score 0):

Did you register with the GSM network via `AT+COPS`?

You can check via `AT+COPS?`.

Comment: I just checked  and it returned something. The issue here is that it is not consistent. I'm still working on it. The next time it starts doing that I'll check with AT+COPS?.

Answer (score 0):

The settings for receiving messages were probably changed. Check with:

```
AT+CNMI=?
```

And you can set the setting to directly display a received message

```
AT+CNMI=1,2,0,0,0
```